# 0 being passed as an optional parameter to a class' method, param not found

Tags: python, input, parameters, zero, option-type

I have a class file LinkedListADT.py and within that I have the class LinkedList. One method I have defined for this class is as follows:

```
def test(self, index=None):
    if index:
        print(str(index))
    else:
        print("Index not found")
```

Now, from my other file (not the class) I have defined the following function:

```
def test():
    tester = LinkedListADT.LinkedList()
    tester.test(0)
```

The result being printed is "Index not found" -- My question is, can 0 be passed as an optional input to a method or regular function?

I am quite new to Python and I'm assuming 0 is being interpreted as false. Whether or not this is the case, is there a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, `0` is considered as "falsey". The documentation lists other ["falsey" values](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

```
print bool(0)
# False
```

But you can check like this

```
def test(self, index=None):
    if index is not None:
        print(str(index))
    else:
        print("Index not found")
```

This program makes sure that the input is not `None` and if it is not, it is user provided (irrespective of its Truthiness).